# Cannot login this website using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, web, web-scraping

I am trying to login this website: https://vn.ku6110.net/Home/Index
by using Selenium. Using Selenium, the site keeps telling me that the username or password are incorrect. But when I manually login, everthing is good. I think this site have some alogrithm to detect auto-login using software. Is that true or my code have some bugs? The code runs well except that it can not login (I am sure that the username and password are correct). Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://vn.ku6110.net/")
try:
    sign_in_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "loginbutton"))
    )
    sign_in_button.click()

    tk = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "accountId"))
    )
    tk.clear()
    tk.send_keys("*******") #this is my username

    mk = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "accountPwd"))
    )
    mk.clear()
    mk.send_keys("********") #this is my password

    sign_in_button_2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "signin"))
    )
    sign_in_button_2.click()
except:
    print("error")
```

Comment: This site also has geographical restrictions which may be affecting you

Comment: @Vlad I can access this site in my country normally

Comment: Bạn sẽ cần ai đó ở Việt Nam để giúp bạn

Comment: @Vlad It is very difficult to find someone here in Viet Nam to help me. Could you fake an IP from VietNam and access this site from your place :)) ?